# Get average of all contents of a List<List<int>>

Tags: c#, list, average

I am looking to get the average of each object in a list of lists. So the first of each list, the second of each list, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show some input and expected output? I can interpret it as either averaging each List<int>, or as Averaging each item - by position - in List<int> over List<List<int>> ..

Comment: Your question is not worded clearly. Suppose your lists are listA, listB, listC.  You want a new list, listAv where listAv[0] is the average of listA[0], listB[0] and listC[0], and so on?

Comment: **Show some code** that shows what you've tried so far.

Comment: @EricLippert that is what I want, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that list is a `List<List<int>>` this should give you a `List<double>` with Averages:

```
var values = list.Select(x => x.Average());
```

If you want to access a specific list's average by it's index than you could do:

```
 var values = list.Select((x,index) => new { idx = index,avg = x.Average() }) 
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.idx, x => x.avg);
```

This should give you a `Dictionary<int, double>` which Keys are indices and Values are averages.

Comment: (Note: Average will throw an InvalidOperationException on empty sequences.)

Comment: Possible to turn "list.Select(x => x.Average())" into a List<int>?

Comment: @user3397642 yes. Because Average method returns a single result like int.Therefore that Select will return a List<int>

Comment: It returns a List<double>.

Comment: Then cast the result to int by `Select(x => (int)x.Average())` or instead of casting use a rounding function.

Comment: @user3397642 sorry I miss that.even if the List is a List<int> average returns double result. you can cast it to integer if you want

Comment: Is it possible to get the average of each list's item, instead?

Such as:

{10,5,7}
{11,4,9}
{12,6,8}
=
{11,4,8}